# Getting ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I know that there are similar questions asked.  I’m not able to find one that I can leverage.  I keep getting the following error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Not sure what is wrong with code, as I’m still learning Python.

> File H:\ code library\Python\T900_Dashboard.py Line 57, in 
> SQLCaseWhen1 = [(T900_DashboardFile[‘NAICS CD (Parent)’] in
> Power_Sector),\
>
> File “C:\Users\DC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py”,
> line 1478, in *nonzero* raise ValueError(

My code looks like:

```
Power_Sector = [‘221101’, ‘221102’, ‘221103’, ‘926131’]

SQLCaseWhen1([T900_DashboardFile[‘NAICS CD (Parent)’] in Power_Sector), (T900_DashboardFile[‘Industry Sector’] == ‘ENERGY’)

SQLCaseThen1 = [‘Power Generation’, ‘Oil & Gas / Energy’]

T900_DashboardFile1[‘Internal Sector’] = np.select(SQLCaseWhen1,SQLCaseThen1, default=‘’)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong in multiple places. I think you are looking for the below. Also, use pandas `isin()` and not python `in`, because you need to use a pandas method. You can only use normal python with pandas when going row-wise with `lambda x:`:

```
Power_Sector = ['221101', '221102', '221103', '926131']

SQLCaseWhen1 = ([T900_DashboardFile['NAICS CD (Parent)'].isin(Power_Sector)).tolist(), 
                (T900_DashboardFile['Industry Sector'] == 'ENERGY').tolist()]

SQLCaseThen1 = ['Power Generation', 
                'Oil & Gas / Energy']

T900_DashboardFile1['Internal Sector'] = np.select(SQLCaseWhen1,SQLCaseThen1, default='')
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.   Received an error the first time that I ran code.  I dropped the 2nd tolist() then ran without any issues.

Comment: @covershaker some parentheses were missing. Fixed now.